# Eclipse Debug Evaluation Window Goes Away

Tags: eclipse

Whenever I hover my mouse over a variable when debugging, I get this extraordinarily useful expression window that lets me see the quantities associated with the object as a whole and/or its sub-objects.

However when I click on any other window outside Eclipse, it immediately disappears and I have to hover back again on the same variable to bring it back.

This is very inconvenient and annoying. Is there a way to prevent this from happening? Basically I want it to go away ONLY if I click on some other area inside of eclipse IDE. Till then I want it to stay put.

Answer (score 0):

Try Window -> Perspective -> OpenPerspective -> Debug.

In the debug perspective you should see a variables tab that shows all current variable values, and it will continue to show even when you click off of the application.

[image]